# Multicast Routing over Wlan and Eth0 interface

Tags: linux, multicast, raspberry-pi3, bonjour

I want to make my Raspberry PI model 3 as a router that is as follows -

Computer will be connected to RPI via Ethernet (eth0) interface 
Phone will be connected to RPI over Wifi (wlan0) interface.

I was able to setup a interfaces with the help of the following links -

https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/

But I am not able to do the multicast routing from wlan0 to eth0 (or) vice versa Can you please help me with it. I need to route bonjour packets over the interfaces.

Note:

1. both the interfaces wlan and eth are supporting MULTICAST ( verified with ifconfig command ) I was able to get **UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST** for both the interfaces.
2. I have tried using the following commands for multicasting -

**route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0 

route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev wlan0**

Comment: You should post your question here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [avahi-daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/avahi-daemon.conf.5.html#contenttoc6) to reflect mDNS queries between interfaces. Some basic configuration like this in `avahi-daemon.conf` should be enough:

```
[server]
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
enable-dbus=no
allow-interfaces=eth0,wlan0

[publish]
disable-publishing=yes

[reflector]
enable-reflector=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old discussion but I tried the given answer and it broke LAN DNS, so don't do it. Instead, edit file:

```
nano /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
```

change this one line to ‘yes’:

```
enable-reflector=yes
```

restart the service:

```
service avahi-daemon restart
```

check to see if the ports are detected automatically:

```
systemctl status avahi-daemon.service
```

Takes a minute for new services to be discovered and appear. Works on Buster. The app [Discovery](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/discovery-dns-sd-browser/id1381004916?mt=12) (formerly Bonjour Browser) is helpful to verify mDNS ZEROCONF multicast packets are getting across. Also there's an iOS app.